# Why is map::find finding something it shouldn't be there?

Tags: c++, dictionary, find

I have defined these structs

```
typedef struct SApair
{
    SApair();
    SApair(State state, Action action);

    State state;
    Action action;

    bool operator<( const SApair& n) const
    { 
        return (this->state.m_avgDpsXHealthEnemyGroup < n.state.m_avgDpsXHealthEnemyGroup
                && this->state.m_avgDpsXHealthGroup < n.state.m_avgDpsXHealthGroup
                && this->state.m_distToClosestEnemyGroup < n.state.m_distToClosestEnemyGroup); //TODO - DEFINE A PROPER OPERATOR 
    }


} SApair;

struct State
{
    State();

    Group m_avgDpsXHealthGroup;
    Group m_avgHealthGroup; //LOW, MID, HIGH
    Group m_distToClosestEnemyGroup;
    Group m_avgDpsXHealthEnemyGroup; 
    Group m_avgEnemyHealthGroup;
}
```

and this enums

```
typedef enum x{ATTACK   = 0, 
               HOLD     = 1, 
               FLEE     = 2,
               COUNT    = 3} Action;


typedef enum y{NA       = -1, //Not Available
               LOW      = 0,
               MID      = 1,
               HIGH     = 2} Group;
```

I have a map

```
std::map<SApair, float>* q_map;
```

At one point, the map contains on single element (map size is 1):

```
sapair = {m_avgDpsXHealthGroup=-1 m_avgHealthGroup=-1_distToClosestEnemyGroup=-1 ...}
action = 0.0f
```

I create a new SApair element

```
SApair sapair = SApair(...);
sapair.state = {MID, LOW, HIGH, -1, -1} //This has been summed up by me for this stackoverflow post, but you get the idea
sapair.action = ATTACK;
```

So, clearly, sapair is different than what's in q_map[0].

However, the find method seems to be finding sapair in q_map

```
if(q_map->find(sapair) != q_map->end())
{
    //I don't understand why it enters here
}
```

What am I missing?

Could it be something with the < operator defined in SApair?

I certainly can't figure it out.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If `q_map` is a *pointer* to a map, then what exactly is `q_map[0]->first` supposed to be doing? I didn't know maps supported `operator ->` for accessing... well.. anything. Am I really that tired?

Comment: Your `<` returns false if *any* of the comparisons is false -- is that what you want?  `m_avgDpsXHealthEnemyGroup` in your two values is equal, so your comparison returns false because it is not less than.

Comment: I think you're code will NOT even be compiled.. Could you show me specific code which can be compiled & run?

Comment: @WhozCraig My mistake, this is not actually in the code, it was me trying to sum things up for this post. I meant to say that there's just one element in the map, at position 0, and with that characteristics. I edited my original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `operator<` contains:

```
//TODO - DEFINE A PROPER OPERATOR
```

Which is appropriate and the source of the problem.

Currently the operator only return `true` if *all three* properties of the item's state are smaller than in the item it is compared to. If now for example two properties of an item `a` are smaller than for `b` and one is larger, then `a < b` returns false.

But `b < a` will also return false, since only property of `b` is smaller than the corresponding property of `a`.

Since neither  `a` nor `b` are smaller than each other, they are considered to be equal.

Since unexpected items are considered to be equal this leads to unexpected results when searching for items with `find()`.

A better `operator<()` would be:

```
bool operator<( const SApair& n) const
{ 
    if (this->state.m_avgDpsXHealthEnemyGroup < n.state.m_avgDpsXHealthEnemyGroup)
        return true;
    if (this->state.m_avgDpsXHealthGroup < n.state.m_avgDpsXHealthGroup)
        return true;
    if (this->state.m_distToClosestEnemyGroup < n.state.m_distToClosestEnemyGroup)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This answers why it is entering the if clause as if it had found sapair in q_map. Thanks a lot. I'm still at a loss in how to properly define the operator. I don't NECESSARILY need a less operator defined, but I did that because I read it was needed because the elements in a map are ordered. Is there a better way to do it? In the end, all I want is to be able to tell apart two different objects, so that if sapair is not found in the map, it can be inserted.

Comment: @FerranMG operator<() is a default compare function used by maps, sets and a lot of c++ algirithms. You can explicitly define different comparator as a third template parameter of your map. Like this: `typedef std::map<KeyType, ValueType, CompareType> MyMap;` Remember that CompareType must implement `bool CompareType::operator()(KeyType, KeyType);`. See this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map

Comment: @FerranMG: I added an `operator<()` implementation that does give a reasonable "equal".

Comment: @sth Thanks for your help, it worked and helped me understand what the issue was.

Comment: @MichałGóral This is interesting, but it seems only works in C++ 11 and 14. I'm currently using an older version and can't switch to a newer one. Thanks for the link, regardless. It's interesting.

Comment: @FerranMG read up on "strict weak ordering" - which matters completely for things like this.